# Triggering cloud functions on folders - is it possible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to configure the cloud function `trigger-bucket` parameter to be a folder in a GCS bucket?

For example, imagine we have the following:

```
gs://a_bucket/a_folder
```

Instead of setting `--trigger-bucket gs://a_bucket` when deploying, I need to set it at the folder level i.e. `--trigger-bucket gs://a_bucket/a_folder/`.

However, I get the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) argument --trigger-bucket:
>   Invalid value 'gs://a_bucket/a_folder/': Bucket must only contain
>   lower case Latin letters, digits and characters . _ -. It must start
>   and end with a letter or digit and be from 3 to 232 characters long.
>   You may optionally prepend the bucket name with gs:// and append / at
>   the end.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to set the trigger at the folder level.

However, one workaround I found is that you can perform it programmatically in the Cloud Function by hooking into the `name` attribute of the change notification as **it contains the folder(s) and the filename**.

E.g. a `a_sample.txt` file which is located in `gs://a_bucket/a_folder/`, the `name` attribute will contain `a_folder/a_sample.txt` as a string value.

So, you can then filter on the folder you are interested in. The trade-offs:

1. It's not pretty!
2. Your cloud function will be triggered for **all** bucket events - even the ones you are not interested in.

If you can live with that, then it's the way to go (until Google support triggering at the folder level).

Comment: Does google support triggering it at the folder level now?